# Showing that an isometric deformation transforms the surface normals at corresponding points.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am basically trying to see that if given an isometric deformation $\Phi$ between two surfaces i.e.

\begin{equation}
\Phi : \boldsymbol{x}(u,v) \to \boldsymbol{y}(u,v)
\end{equation}

the normal vector $\boldsymbol{n}_x(u_0,v_0)$ transforms into $\boldsymbol{n}_y(u_0,v_0) = \Phi(\boldsymbol{n}_x(u_0,v_0))$.  Can this be proved?? I would like to clarify that an isometric deformation is slightly stronger than an isometry requirement as it implies a continuous bending as explained in [this link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Deformation,_isometric).
An obvious example of this is the folding of a flat sheet of paper into a cylinder or the deformation between a catenoid and a right helicoid. A non-example would be a right circular helicoid and a left circular helicoid which are locally isometric.

Comment: Two observations: 1. An isometry of surfaces does not act on normal directions without additional information. 2. If the surfaces are in Euclidean three-space and we map normal vectors via "Send $x_u \times x_v$ to $y_u \times y_v$ (up to positive scaling), this is false, since as stated we have no control over orientation.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks a lot!! Just a small additional question. I can post this as a separate question. But how would one try to mathematically formulate the process of a continuous bending as opposed to just a local isometry??

Comment: Ah, I see: You're thinking of a _one parameter family of local isometries_, and here the answer to your questions is _yes_. (Surprisingly, a left-handed helicoid _can_ be smoothly deformed to a right-handed helicoid through local isometries: Deform to a catenoid, and "keep going".) I'll write up some details here about how to make this idea precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Eucl}{\mathbf{E}}\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$The idea of a *continuous isometric deformation* can be made precise as a path in the space of local isometries, but can also be formulated in more concrete terms:

Let $U$ be an open subset of the plane and let $\Phi_{0}:U \to \Eucl^{3}$ be a regular parametrization of a (possibly immersed) surface $S_{0}$ in Euclidean three-space. We can define an *isometric deformation* of $S_{0}$ to be a smooth mapping $\Phi: U \times (-\eps, \eps) \to \Eucl^{3}$ (for some real $\eps > 0$) such that

- $\Phi(u, v, 0) = \Phi_{0}(u, v)$ for all $(u, v)$ in $U$;
- For each $t$ in $(-\eps, \eps)$, the restriction $\Phi_{t} = \Phi(\cdot, \cdot, t):U \to \Eucl^{3}$ is a regular parametrization of a surface $S_{t}$;
- Let $g$ denote the Euclidean metric. For each $t$ in $(-\eps, \eps)$, the metric $\Phi_{t}^{*}g$ is equal to $\Phi_{0}^{*}g$. (This condition can be expressed in terms of dot products of the partials of $\Phi_{t}$, and implies that if $\Phi(u, v, 0) \mapsto \Phi(u, v, t)$ defines a mapping $S_{0} \to S_{t}$, then this mapping is a local isometry. We state things in this roundabout way because, for example, we might want to view a helicoid as a smooth deformation of a catenoid, see also below.)

For such a deformation, the unit normal fields "vary continuously" because they can be calculated in terms of the partials of $\Phi_{t}$.

Incidentally, as noted in the comments, helicoids of opposite chirality actually *are* deformable into each other (either locally, or globally through immersions), e.g., by
$$
\Phi(u, v, t) = \cos t (\cosh v \sin u, -\cosh v\cos u, -v) - \sin t(\sinh v\cos u, \sinh v\sin u, u).
$$
(At $t = \pi/2$ the helicoid is right-handed; at $t = -\pi/2$ it is left-handed.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your answer has been very helpful. One thing is particularly surprising however, that is the deformation between helicoids of two opposite chiralities. I thought the chirality is due to a determinant and so going from one chirality to the opposite in a continuous fashion indicates that one cannot do it through a 1-parameter family of local isometries as we will hit a surface of zero curvature somewhere in between(some sort of mean value theorem0. That part is slightly confusing.  Also, you say immersions, can one strengthen it to embeddings???

Comment: Could you take a look at this link  as it captures my thoughts precisely : https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/on-the-applicability-and-deformation-of-surfaces/AF566E4C5A1EADB01A5A01C36AAC872E#

Comment: At the moment I don't have access to the linked journal article, but based on the abstract, the equivalence Sen considers must be stronger than deformability through local isometries. (For instance, there might be a requirement that intermediate surfaces are ruled, or some other condition that prevents passing through the catenoid, which would prevent helicoids of opposite chirality from being mutually deformable.) <> Regarding embeddings, if $U$ is small then the framework sketched here is already embedded, but "globally" that looks like a subtle, difficult issue.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations. You have been of great help. I had similar thoughts about what the paper must be saying. I was able to download it and am uploading it here in case you have the time : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q5PQpRCJNTCQ6s6TX7Ssvn32e-w5ul6O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I must add that the context for these questions comes from mechanics, particularly material deformation.

Comment: Just a quick note that I'm reading Forsyth, which Sen cites, but still don't understand Sen's example of the pair of Beltrami surfaces or see how to reconcile Sen's claims and my understanding. Sen's and Forsyth's definitions of _continuous deformation_ are material, but it still seems they should be captured by the definition with $\Phi$.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry about the repeated comments. But these issues do not seem to be dealt with in any book on differential geometry I could find, although the concepts involved are elementary yet subtle and probably only matter when discussed in a physical context. I think your earlier comment about this kind of deformation requiring that the intermediate surfaces are ruled is right. The generatrices seem to be preserved in the kind of deformation Sen talks about.

Comment: [Forsyth](https://archive.org/details/lecturesondiffer00forsuoft/page/392/mode/2up), p. 392, confirms that Beltrami is deforming through ruled surfaces, so that seems the likely explanation. <> Yours is a neat question, and now I'll keep an eye out for Forsyth's book in used book shops. :)

Comment: Coincidentally, if you'll pardon the self-promotion, a student (X. Wang) and I have a paper related to bending Clairaut metrics (of the form $E(u)\, du^2 + G(u)\, dv^2$) accepted in the Tohoku Math Journal. I'll try to remember to add the details here when the paper appears.

Comment: Thank you for all the interest and patience you have shown. Can you mention the month and issue when the paper will appear in the Tohoku Math Journal so that I can look out for it??Also I just wanted to confirm whether deformation through ruled surfaces is sufficient and necessary to ensure that the rulings are preserved?

Comment: We haven't received the page proofs, but unless COVID causes undue delay I expect the paper to appear in 2021. <> Yes, the assertion about deforming through ruled surfaces is my understanding of Sen (and Forsyth).

Comment: I realised that only for minimal surfaces such as the isometric deformation from a catenoid to helicoid, the normals are actually preserved. I have also posted another related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183286/… I would be happy to receive your insight on this.

Comment: The paper will appear as _Clairaut surfaces in Euclidean three-space_, Tôhoku Mathematical Journal, Vol. 74, No. 2 (June, 2022).

Comment: Thank you. I will look out for it.