# Catenoid - Heliocid like deformations and self intersections.

Tags: differential-geometry

I was trying to understand the well known catenoid-helicoid deformation and the following two questions propped up.

1. The intermediate minimal surfaces in the transformation are self-intersecting. Most animations that I looked at seem to indicate this at some points. But I came across [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Morgan-Chabanon/publication/335614723/figure/fig1/AS:800538983686144@1567874775394/a-c-Helicoids-are-continuous-and-isometric-transformations-of-catenoids-a-Schematic.png) image that seems to suggest otherwise. Can one restrict the parameter range to avoid the self intersections?
2. Aside of minimal surfaces, I was wondering if a similar bending expression giving a family of surfaces can be obtained for the deformation from an oblique helicoid to a circular hyperboloid of one sheet?? I checked that they are isometric. Any suggestions or references are welcome.

Comment: A note on 1.: In the standard circle in the space of minimal surfaces restricted to one full turn, the surfaces do visually appear to intersect at intermediate parameter values and at points close to the central curve. <> On the other hand, it's possible to build a paper model of a catenoid and deform it to a helicoid. While that physical deformation may not be through isometries (paper stretches!), it does suggest that it's possible to bend one turn of a catenoid isometrically in Euclidean three-space to one turn of a helicoid (with intermediate surfaces maybe not having helicoidal symmetry).